# C# Save all of scrollable Panel as Image

Tags: c#, image, save, panel

I'm trying to save all of a panel to a JPG, I already asked this question but the answer wasn;t what I was looking for. The problem is that the panel has a scrollbar (not enough space for all elements) but it doesn't print what is at the bottom of the panel, only visible elements.

```
public void DrawControl(Control control,Bitmap bitmap)
{
    control.DrawToBitmap(bitmap,control.Bounds);
    foreach (Control childControl in control.Controls)
    {
        DrawControl(childControl,bitmap);
    }
}

public void SaveBitmap()
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(this.panel1.Width, this.panel.Height);

    this.panel.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.panel.Width, this.panel.Height));
    foreach (Control control in panel1.Controls)
    {
        DrawControl(control, bmp);
    }

    bmp.Save("d:\\panel.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could scroll the panel and Get a Bitmap of each scrolled content, then merge the bitmap parts ?

```
    public void SaveBitmap(System.Windows.Forms.Panel CtrlToSave, string fileName)
    {
        Point oldPosition = new Point(this.HorizontalScroll.Value, this.VerticalScroll.Value);

        CtrlToSave.PerformLayout();

        ComposedImage ci = new ComposedImage(new Size(CtrlToSave.DisplayRectangle.Width, CtrlToSave.DisplayRectangle.Height));

        int visibleWidth = CtrlToSave.Width - (CtrlToSave.VerticalScroll.Visible ? SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth : 0);
        int visibleHeightBuffer = CtrlToSave.Height - (CtrlToSave.HorizontalScroll.Visible ? SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarHeight : 0);

        //int Iteration = 0;

        for (int x = CtrlToSave.DisplayRectangle.Width-visibleWidth; x >= 0 ; x -= visibleWidth)
        {               

            int visibleHeight = visibleHeightBuffer;

            for (int y = CtrlToSave.DisplayRectangle.Height-visibleHeight; y >= 0 ; y -= visibleHeight)
            {
                CtrlToSave.HorizontalScroll.Value = x;
                CtrlToSave.VerticalScroll.Value = y;

                CtrlToSave.PerformLayout();

                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(visibleWidth, visibleHeight);

                CtrlToSave.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, visibleWidth, visibleHeight));
                ci.images.Add(new ImagePart(new Point(x,y),bmp));

                ///Show image parts
                //using (Graphics grD = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                //{
                //    Iteration++;
                //    grD.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue,new Rectangle(0,0,bmp.Width-1,bmp.Height-1));
                    //grD.DrawString("x:"+x+",y:"+y+",W:"+visibleWidth+",H:"+visibleHeight + " I:" + Iteration,new Font("Segoe UI",9f),Brushes.Red,new Point(2,2));                        
                //}

                if (y - visibleHeight < (CtrlToSave.DisplayRectangle.Height % visibleHeight))
                    visibleHeight = CtrlToSave.DisplayRectangle.Height % visibleHeight;

                if (visibleHeight == 0)
                    break;
            }

            if (x - visibleWidth < (CtrlToSave.DisplayRectangle.Width % visibleWidth))
                visibleWidth = CtrlToSave.DisplayRectangle.Width % visibleWidth;                
            if (visibleWidth == 0)
                break;
        }

        Bitmap img = ci.composeImage();
        img.Save(fileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

        CtrlToSave.HorizontalScroll.Value = oldPosition.X;
        CtrlToSave.VerticalScroll.Value = oldPosition.Y;
    }



public class ComposedImage
{
    public Size dimensions;
    public List<ImagePart> images;

    public ComposedImage(Size dimensions)
    {
        this.dimensions = dimensions;
        this.images = new List<ImagePart>();
    }

    public ComposedImage(Size dimensions, List<ImagePart> images)
    {
        this.dimensions = dimensions;
        this.images = images;
    }

    public Bitmap composeImage()
    {
        if (dimensions == null || images == null)
            return null;

        Bitmap fullbmp = new Bitmap(dimensions.Width, dimensions.Height);
        using (Graphics grD = Graphics.FromImage(fullbmp))
        {
            foreach (ImagePart bmp in images)
            {
                grD.DrawImage(bmp.image, bmp.location.X, bmp.location.Y);
            }
        }
        return fullbmp;
    }
}

public class ImagePart
{
    public Point location;
    public Bitmap image;

    public ImagePart(Point location, Bitmap image)
    {
        this.location = location;
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked well for me with a minor mod for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

The bitmap is too small of course, make it as large as panel.DisplayRectangle.  Don't draw the panel if you don't want to get the scrollbars in the image.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is an old thread but I found a much simpler way to save the contents of a single panel as an image. This will work for a single panel, currently one of my reports prints out to 1560 x 6043 using this approach.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    panel1.AutoSize = true;
    panel1.Refresh();

    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height))
    {

       panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size));
       string fileName = "Full_Domain_Report_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH_mm_ss") + ".png";       
       bmp.Save(@"C:\temp\" + fileName, ImageFormat.Png); // make sure path exists!

    }

    panel1.AutoSize = false;
    panel1.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: The question asks for Scrollable Panel but it only saves the visible area.